# draw dependency graph for a java class

Tags: java, class, tree, dependencies

Heyho,
I'm searching for a tool like JDepend to draw a graph for a java classfile. JDepend seams to be fine, but it's not resolving the deps from the deps (maybe I'm just missing some special options?). A direct output into .dot format or an image would be nice to have.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JavaDepend](http://www.javadepend.com), it gives many features for dependency needs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [UMLGraphDoc](http://www.umlgraph.org/doc/cd-umldoc.html). I've used it, and found it quite useful.

It will draw diagrams based on relations that it inferred automatically, or that were specified by special javadoc tags.

Comment: Yes, but this one uses java source files (javadoc) rather then class files (isn't that what the OP is looking for?)

Comment: Right, I've got class files (got the sources as well, but it's 13kloc written in 48h from 2.5people - so there's nothing you can call documentation). So a solution working with the class files is the best way.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Yes, UMLGraphDoc runs on the source files. It does not need javadocs however. If they are there it will use them, but it can also do diagrams based just on type hierarchies etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by dependencies from the dependencies, and there's certainly no .dot format, but try Fractality here:

http://www.edmundkirwan.com/pub/index.html

Comment: .dot format means DOT Language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) notation in text file which can be used with eg. GraphViz to generate all kinds of graphs.